# pytest, How do you break up rather long test?

Tags: django, pytest

I'm writing my first pytest test, and it is rather long (currently 120 lines)

It tests the store's `checkout` process, What it does is roughly following:

- grab product info
- add_to_cart
- add purchaser information (phone, name, address etc)
- (extra) add coupons or points to use
- create an order from cart
- handle payment (bypassing actual payment gateway, but still need to do something like stock decreasing, change order status etc)
- cancel the order (because created order data needs to be reused, I'm putting them together)

How to break up pytest tests when many objects need to be shared..

Comment: Probably `fixture` can help you: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html

Comment: You could also use the package `factory_boy` to create instances with random data. While it takes a bit of setup I've found that it has improved test readability overall.